# How to read alert of Excel file

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI for reading excel files. In my scenario, I put input fields in the Excel cells and read the output from the excel file, but whenever I put some wrong combinations of input into the excel then excel generates an alert box with an error message on it. My Ques is How can I read those alert messages?

For example, there is a SEX field in the Excel and I put "ABC" on that field then an alert will popup with message `Please provide Valid Sex.`

Is there any way to read Popup messages from Excel using Apache POI.

Comment: How are those fields constraints enforced in the Excel file, through VBA macros?

Comment: Yes, using macros.

Comment: Recent versions of Apache POI support extracting the macro data via VBAMacroExtractor and VBAMacroReader - but you would need to find or implement a VBA implementation that can actually execute them